# How to control/hold zoom in and zoom out in Google charts Column Charts

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-visualization

I am using google chart column charts in Angular 2 by ng2-google-charts, which we get new real data points for every 5 seconds. Where graph can hold a 200 data points. For every new data point I get, I push it to graph Data. And calls the graph properties again.

like `public graphReloadMethod():void {
      columnChartOptions = {
      chartType: 'ColumnChart',
      dataTable: this.items,
      options: this.columnChartOptionsJSON
  };
}`

Where in the above

this.items consists of all Datapoints.
this.columnChartOptions consists all the options of Chart.

Here I am using zoom option(Explorer), for existing data points, it is getting zoomed, its fine.

When I am in zoom, and when I get a new data point, the graph getting reset.

**I don't want zoom to be disturbed when I get new data point**

Can any of you, help me for this.

Sample example regarding new data points
JSfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/gaddam/tad2z03h/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/gaddam/tad2z03h/1/)

Comment: see the answer here --> [Google chart looses zoom after draw](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40745775/5090771)

Comment: Hello WhiteHat, 

                       The above question is same as my requirement. But the answer over there is not working as expected. 
Note:- I am working on angular 2 Platform, using ng2-googleCharts

Comment: please clarify what _is not working as expected_...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gaddam/tad2z03h/1/

This is my code, When I am zooming to a point, in middle if I get new runtime datapoint, My graph should not reset. It should be in the same zoom position only. Is there is any option for that. 

In the link which u had given to me, There is no real runtime time datapoints to check my case.