# Google visualization chart default zoomed in

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to get Google visualization line charts to zoom in as much as it can by default, and showing the newest data (region to the most right on the chart). 
But I can't find any options for it on Googles line charts documentation. 
The only thing I can see is explorer.maxZoomIn which is how much the user can possible zoom in.

Is there any default value I can set to have the chart zoomed in on a region?

Comment: there are no options for default zoom, but you can set a specific `viewWindow` on either axis, here is an example --> [Google chart looses zoom after call to chart.draw()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748353/5090771)