# Google Chart: How to sync zoom on differents charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, chart.js

Having several charts in a page, I want that when zooming in a chart, this zoom is also done in the other charts

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40748353/5090771) has the code you're looking for...

Comment: HI WhiteHat, i saw that documentation, but, when i did some zoom, the data dissapear and I have to search it, how i can center the data?.

Comment: sorry, I don't follow your question...